# Excel as a calculation engine on the web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, architecture

I have an existing business application written in Excel which the client would like to make accessible on the web.

I started off thinking I would have to reimplement it, however it has occurred to me that it would make the job much easier, maintain the knowledge and value in the spreadsheet and make the new tool more flexible if I could connect the existing spreadsheet as a data source from ASP.NET and use it as an engine.

This sounded like a good solution until I considered that Excel would spawn a new process for each connection and we would likely get locking issues.

Is this assumption correct? Is there a component that I could use to manage this?

Note: I have seen Excel Services but Sharepoint is not an option. The application will be a public facing website but only some users will be allowed to access the application. Conservative estimate: 1000 monthly active users of which half have paid to access the application.

Comment: I don't have a link handy but I've read in the past that MS strongly discourages exposes office elements through a web server. I'll see if I can dig up the link...

Comment: PAID access for accessing something with that many people which connects to EXCEL!!! It should be connecting to a DB, I would drop the excel and force everyone onto the web version unless offline access is a must but that's not too much of a problem

Comment: It's not going to be connecting to the spreadsheet that people will be using internally. The spreadsheet will be deployed in the App_Data folder as part of the application. 

I'd have to convert all of this business knowledge into ASP.NET - thus making it much harder to change the calculation and add or remove factors which influence the calculation. 

I agree in an ideal world that a database would remove the performance issue but there's a tight deadline and this sounds like a more flexible solution that doesn't throw away months and months of investment that went into the business app.

Comment: @Rob Stevenson-Leggett Why would anyone spend months and months on an EXCEL business system! I mean I don't want to sound like the voice of doom but if there was any inkling of something like 1000 monthly users excel is not just NOT to be used for it! I really think they should cut their losses and start again with a fully fledged browser based system

Comment: @CodeBlend Many businesses use Excel to complex models that are very difficult to understand, for example pricing systems for trading sports spread betting. Excel is a good fit because business users understand it. People do spend months and treat them like apps. SpreadsheetGear and Apose Excel takes the spreadsheet and turns it into a Calculation engine so you treat the excel model as an API. Honestly Excel apps are very common - the knowledge and investments are massive - why replace that with a web based system which is likely to be inflexible for the business and spend more of their money?

Comment: I see what you are saying but having delved into the world of coding for both desktop and web although yes you may start limiting the user at the end of the day I think this is a good thing in the end but I admit it doesn't fit all purposes especially if your users are excel literate. I have found that because people find it easy to get on with they end up using excel to try and accomplish some rather advanced tasks and end up with VB code and all sorts which ends up very messy and the more users introduced the more problems arise.

Comment: @CodeBlend Agreed. I'm absolutely against VBA but tools like the ones mentioned below can bridge the gap without having to spend months and months analysing how a complex spreadsheet works while meaning the users could update it themselves without using a perhaps rushed and not fit for purpose web interface.

Comment: @Rob Stevenson-Leggett See now that is an example to everyone else on how to have an amicable conversation without bickering =)

Comment: Ended up using Aspose.Cells - it's really quick, SpreadsheetGear was just as good when I did a prototype though. I'm a bit worried about what will happen when the business users change the spreadsheet! I wrote a validator to check for named ranges etc when they upload it into the CMS but still. In hindsight, might have been more robust to rewrite in .NET but definitely not as quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Office automation is NOT supported by MS in this scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)...

MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel)...

Another option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx

IF you need more like rendering, formulas etc. then there are different commercial libraries like Aspose.Cells and Flexcel and Spreadsheetgear...

Answer (score 2):

For the usage you describe even if it's only read only access to the information, excel is not designed for this and I foresee problems. I would strongly recommend you import the excel information into a DB and write code to access it!

Comment: Agreed, I would avoid this solution like the plague!

Comment: I disagree within the timescales. SpreadsheetGear seems do to do what I want. http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/calcengine.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Excel calculation engines offered by third parties that are designed to be able to be used on the server. A couple that come to mind are Aspose Cells and SpreadsheetGear.